# Google Maps API Key not working on new proyect

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I am working on integrating some google maps functionality into a Xamarin Forms project, since I haven't found some decent videos on the topic I am using some [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#platform-configuration) as a reference for my code.
Right now I am trying to display a new Map but I am showed with only a gray box, I know this is caused by the API key not working and the following message in the debug output.
[image: output]

Here's how I have set up my API key in the Android manifest, I followed the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#add_key)

```xml
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyAPIKey"/>
```

In the demo proyect from the documentation they used another set up, though it doesn`t fix my problem

```xml
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="myAPIKey" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the exact steps provided here?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#add_key 
and added your api key in code?
your api key should be like

and make sure your package name for android is exactly same as mention while creating api key on console.

Comment: Yes my API key is in the android manifest I just removed it from the code to in order to it share here

Answer (score 0):

An important thing is the step 5 `On the Restrict and rename API key page, set the restrictions:` from [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#add_key).

In order to obtain the SHA1 key, you should follow: [Finding your Keystore's Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=macos)

You may have different keys for your debug and production builds, so beware.